# Pegando o conteúdo de uma imagem que eu fiz da minha pasta

Tags: php, laravel, imagem

Bom
eu tenho um formulário que faz upload de images , essas imagens são jogadas no diretório: `uploads/{idcampaign}/images/`

No meu controller PHP como eu faço para acessar essa imagem e pegar seu conteúdo?

```php
    public function get($id) {

      /** @var  UploadedFile $file */

      $image = $this->repository->byId($id)->first();
      $url = "/storage/app/" + $image->path;
      if($image) {
          return response()->file($url , ['Content-Type' => 'image.png | 
      image.jpeg']);
    }
      throw new NotFoundHttpException('image-not-found');
    }
```

Tentei isso e não deu. Eu só preciso chegar na imagem e pegar seu conteúdo para poder retornar para a view.

Comment: Como assim "conteúdo"? O conteúdo da imagem é binário, você não vai conseguir representá-lo diretamente em json. Por que não passa o caminho dela para a view?

Comment: Eu tento passar um <img src="route"> mas essa rota não é acessível publicamente , então estou tentando pegar o "content" da imagem através de um controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando duvidas desse tipo surgirem não exite em consultar a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses). Basicamente você pode usar a função [`file`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-responses), acessado a partir do objeto response.

Aplicando, fica:

```
return response()->file($url);
```

Mas provavelmente será necessario enviar alguns cabeçalhos como resposta, como por exemplo, o mime do arquivo. Exemplo:

```
 return response()->file($url, ['Content-Type' => 'image/png']);
```

Comment: Eu fiz este procedimento e de fato o php navegou ate o arquivo , mas não mandou uma mensagem dizendo que o arquivo não existe ,

message:
"The file "uploads/24/images/2sWc551Kr0WCXLOe9c3hnFTlfKZ4BqTcmu27RsuE.jpeg" does not exist"

Comment: e este é o caminho exato do meu arquivo

Comment: A pasta upload esta no mesmo diretorio que o seu controller?

Comment: não , eu ja reparei isso e coloquei a url certa na busca:
'storage/app/uploads/etc'
mas agr o console me retornou este erro:
"file 0 not found"

Comment: @Gabriel.H Provavelmente ao fazer isso você deve ter subido alguns diretorios, ou usado uma url base para concatenar com o nome do arquivo. Pois se você tiver seguindo o padrão do laravel, seu controller deve estar dentro de `app/http/controllers`, então se você, no momento que for chamar o arquivo, usar caminho relativo, ele vai procurar a partir da pasta controllers. Talvez você possa usar a função `app_path` para procurar o caminho a partir do diretorio app. Exemplo: `app_path() . '/uploads/24/images/2sWc551Kr0WCXLOe9c3hnFTlfKZ4BqTcmu27RsuE.‌​jpeg'`

Comment: Na verdade está em 'storage/app' ,  eu tentei usar 'storage_path' mas não deu , tem uma maneira de eu acessar a pasta 'app' dentro da pasta 'storage'?

Comment: [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#paths) tem todas as funções de path possiveis. Para subir diretorios basta usar `../`. Tipo: `/home/usuario/storage/app/../arquivo.php`. Quando executado o arquivo.php será procurado dentro da pasta storage.

Comment: Não tem a função path que eu preciso , e quando eu monto minha própria URL , mesmo que esteja correta , me retorna um erro como este:
File 0 does not exist

Comment: Eu vi que era um erro de sintaxe , e que usando storage eu consegui chegar no path da imagem